# how to convert a string into an slash-escaped string in python3

Tags: python, python-3.x

```py
def str2escaped_str(s):
```

for example, if the input string s is

```
"biz_entity_name": "dfdfr"
```

the expected return string is

```
\"biz_entity_name\": \"dfdfr\"
```

is there a easy to implement that?
in go it can be:

```golang
    escapedStr := fmt.Sprintf("%q", s)
    escapedStr = escapedStr[1:len(escapedStr)-1]
```

Comment: What do you consider a "slash-escaped string"? Do you just want to escape quotes (both ``'`` and ``"`` or just one?), escape sequences, the escape character ``\`` itself, non-ascii (or any other range) ordinals, ...? Are you looking for the Python ``repr`` of a string, or actually "a single-quoted character literal safely escaped with Go syntax"? Please also provide the example input/output as string *literals* to avoid confusion – ``'\"biz_entity_name\": \"dfdfr\"'`` and ``'\\"biz_entity_name\\": \\"dfdfr\\"'`` are unambiguous  strings but ``\"biz_entity_name\": \"dfdfr\"`` is a SyntaxErrror.

Comment: The results I've gotten from doing a search before are repr or something like that, but that's not what I'm looking for. Your question made me think about the precise definition of this slash-escaped string. After some questioning and thinking, I found out that it is just a string of json. So the answer is simple, just use python's json library. I should close the answer, and don‘t know how to do it.